# Animate.CSS should not repeat the animation every time on scrolling, Instead it should happen only once on the very first scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Can Anyone tell me what mistake am making with in this code?

I am using Animate.CSS Plugin and created a demo below. It should not repeat the animation every time on scrolling, Instead, it should happen only once on the very first scroll

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row animatedParent" style="margin-top: 250px; padding-bottom: 60px;">
  <div class="col-sm-4 animated bounceInUp slow" data-timeout="400"> Content </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.doTimeout(2500, function() {
    $('.repeat.go').removeClass('go');
    return true;
  });
  $.doTimeout(2520, function() {
    $('.repeat').addClass('go');
    return true;
  });
});
```

http://dev.ktimes.co/was20378/scroll/index-scroll.html

Comment: post your js , html code here , so we can help

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.doTimeout(2500, function(){
  $('.repeat.go').removeClass('go');

  return true;
 });
 $.doTimeout(2520, function(){
  $('.repeat').addClass('go');
  return true;
 });
 
});

</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate/css/animations.css" type="text/css">

<div class="row animatedParent" style="margin-top: 250px; padding-bottom: 60px;">
             <div class="col-sm-4 animated bounceInUp slow" data-timeout="400">
                Content
                 </div></div>

Kindly check the Demo Link source code.
THANK YOU

Comment: please post it by editing your code , also refer the libs used in your code ..